# C# DataTable get all distinct values but treat empty cells as "anyvalue"

Tags: c#, datatable, combinations, distinct, group

My DataTable looks something like this:

| id1 | id2 | id3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 3 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |

I want my program to remove all "duplicate combinations", so the table would look like this:

| id1 | id2 | id3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |

Basically I want it to check if other rows are already contained within other rows, while treating the empty cells as a cell that could have any value at all.

I have tried working with the DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true) distinct method and adding column names as parameters but couldn't get it to do exactly what i want.

Also the size of the table is dynamic - There can be an infinite amount of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a good solution.  The distinct doesn't work (using IComarable because it leaves the row with the null instead of the row with values.  I had to add a sort so the row with null is before the one with values.  Then I delete the first row leaving the second row with values.  Also found I had to add dt.AcceptChanges(); because the row did get deleted.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id1", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("id2", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("id3", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns["id1"].AllowDBNull = true;
            dt.Columns["id2"].AllowDBNull = true;
            dt.Columns["id3"].AllowDBNull = true;

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 3, 2 });

            dt = RemoveDuplicates(dt);

        }
        static DataTable RemoveDuplicates(DataTable dt)
        {
            for (int col = dt.Columns.Count - 1; col >= 0; col--)
            {
                dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<int?>(col)).CopyToDataTable(); ;
            }
            for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                bool delete = true;
                for (int col = 0; col <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; col++ )
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[i][col] == DBNull.Value)
                        continue;
                    if((int)dt.Rows[i][col] != (int)dt.Rows[i + 1][col])
                    {
                        delete = false;
                        break;

                    }
                }
                if (delete)
                {
                    dt.Rows[i].Delete();
                    dt.AcceptChanges();
                }
            }

            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: op says "Also the size of the table is dynamic - There can be an infinite amount of columns."

Comment: @BurnsBA : The only thing that needed to be changed was the sort. I modified the code above so it will now work with any number of columns.